# Probability that $t^2 + 2\sqrt{x}t + y = 0 $

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

X and Y are independent
X~Geom(P)
Y~Exp($\lambda $)

Compute the probability that $t^2 + 2\sqrt{x}t + y = 0 $

Steps I've taken so far:

Found where the determinant of the quadratic is $\geq 0$.
$\sqrt{4x - 4y)}$ is positive when $x-y \geq 0$

How do I then find the probability that $x-y \geq 0$ has only one real solution?

Comment: Are you meaning to ask for the probability that your quadratic in $t$ has real solutions? Because the probability that it's exactly zero also depends on $t$ itself, which we're not given any information about.

Comment: Yes, probability that the quadratic in $t$ has real solutions.

Comment: Updated the question. The probability that the quadratic has only one real solution.

Comment: In this case, you're looking for the cases where $x = y$ (the discriminant is exactly zero when there is only one real solution). Since $X$ is a discrete distribution and $Y$ is a continuous distribution, the probability that $x = y$ should be zero.